# Linq Inner join with an Or clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, inner-join

I have a SQL query which I'd like to convert into Linq but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT Distinct Name FROM Context
inner join Nodes_1 on 
Context.Node1Id= Nodes_1.Id OR 
Context.Node2Id= Nodes_1.Id 
where Context.ContextId = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var something = (from a in Context.Where(i => i.ContextId == 1)
                 from b in Nodes_1 
                 where (a.Node1Id == b.Id) || (a.Node2Id == b.Id)
                 select a.Name).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` with `OR` is just a `UNION` of two separate queries with `JOIN`.
So, to reproduce it with LINQ, you should concatenate two linq queries.

Or you may do this:

```
 var query = (from entry in Context
        from node in Nodes_1
        where node.Id==entry.Node1Id ||
              node.Id==entry.Node2Id
        where entry.ContextId==1
        select entry.Name)
        .Distinct();
```

Comment: It gives me the wrong. The same as if I use the SQL query without the OR clause and the second statement following